# Replacing with sed wont work

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, substitution

I have a file called "washington", with capital spelled in 4 different
ways: `Capital, capital, Capitol, capitol`. Use the "sed" command
to replace all of them at once, with the correct spelling: `capital`.

I tried `cat /washington | s '/[Cc]apit[ao]l/capital'` but it wont work.

What do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$ cat /washington | sed 's/[Cc]apit[ao]l/capital/g'
```

Note that you need proper command in quotes. Starts with 's' for 'substitute' and ends with 'g' for 'global'. Global means replace all occurrences in the string.

Comment: Oh, and of course the filename after. Thank you very much. I totally messed up

Comment: @GregLance, the regex can be a little simpler using the `i` flag: `sed  's/capit[ao]l/capital/gi'`

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/[Cc]apit[ao]l/capital/g' <filename>`

If you want to change the file itself, i.e. write back to file

`sed -i 's/[Cc]apit[ao]l/capital/g' <filename>`

If you want to keep a backup (my suggestion) of the original file

`sed -i.bak 's/[Cc]apit[ao]l/capital/g' <filename>` will keep a backup named .bak

(See, i did not use `cat` anywhere)